# vba coding identify negative numbers then perform equation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently undertaking a masters project analysing a large amount of data. I'm trying to calculate the time participants spend asleep by comparing the time when they wake up and the time they fall asleep, currently I've just taken the time where they awoke and the time they fell asleep, which has worked for all but 450 or so particpants. I've worked out the problem is that where participants are falling asleep at 2am and waking at 6am this produces a negative number and the excel calculates this as an extra day saying the particpant is asleep for 30 hours.

I have worked out I effectively need a piece of code that does if x is negative then 1440-value of x for column M

My current code is this:

```
Sub AlterSleep()
    Sleep=columms(13).Select 
    If Sleep < 0 Then
        sleep 1440-sleep 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't even take the time to format your question and REMOVE the -3 down vote favorite that came with the copy/pasting of a bad question, people will not want to help you.

Comment: apologies this is the first time i have ever used anything like this and originally i put it in the wrong forum didn't realized that had pasted across i wont do it in the future as i now know where to post

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely assume that the sleeping duration will always be less than 24 hours, you could calculate it like this:
`duration = ((awakening_time - sleeping_time) + 1440) modulus 1440`

That is, if the formula adds 24 hours without needing it it'll be corrected by taking the modulus.
As this is a very simple formula it could be implemented in the worksheet as a formula, using VBA would just be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateDiff("n")` to calculate the minutes between the two times and `ABS()` to always return a positive number.

> TimeAsleep(#6:00:00 AM#, #02:00:00 AM#) = 240
>
> TimeAsleep(#6:00:00 AM#, #02:00:00 AM#) = 240

```
Function TimeAsleep(TimeWokeUp As Date, TimeFallenToAsleep As Date) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    TimeWokeUp = TimeValue(TimeWokeUp)
    TimeFallenToAsleep = TimeValue(TimeFallenToAsleep)
    result = DateDiff("n", TimeWokeUp, TimeFallenToAsleep)
    TimeAsleep = Abs(result)
End Function
```